# Not able to deploy ASP .net vnext application on VM on Azure using Docker

Tags: asp.net, ssl, docker, asp.net-core

I'm trying to deploy asp .net 5 sample application on Azure VM (ubuntu). I'm using Docker tools for Visual Studio 15.
I'm following http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNET5AppToDockerOnLinuxWithVisualStudio.aspx

**Process 1;**
I have followed below steps;
1. Created sample app using VS15
2. Publish wizard, created new VM
3. Published, keeping same host and container port 80.
4. Exposed 80 port using azure portal

Publish goes through but when opened in IE, it shows page can not be displayed.

I have even created multiple VMs and tried the same but no success.

**Process 2;**
I'm trying to create an image using docker client but it gives TLS error.
Are you trying to connect to a TLS enabled daemon without TLS?
I'm getting this even on my Laptop. which is trying to create the image using 127.0.0.1:2375

Can anyone please help?

I have checked container logs; below is the details.

```
 System.InvalidOperationException: Failed to resolve the following
     dependencies for target framework 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1':
```

Current runtime target framework: 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1 (dnx451)'
    Version:      1.0.0-beta7-15532
    Type:         Mono
    Architecture: x64
    OS Name:      Linux

```
   at Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.Main (System.String[] args)      [0x00000]
 in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()   [0x00000] i
n <filename unknown>:0
 at Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Commo`enter code here`n.EntryPointExecutor.Execute     (System.Reflection.
```

Assembly assembly, System.Strenter code hereing[] args, IServiceProvider    serviceProvider) [0x00
    000] in :0
    at Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync   (System.Collections.Generic.List`1
   args, IRuntimeEnvironment env, System.Runtime.Versioning.FrameworkName    targetFr
    amework) [0x00000] in :0

Answer (score 0):

Husain,
Could you please try the below mentioned two links. Please let me know if you are still facing issues. I will join you in hunting the issue down.

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/announcing-windows-server-2016-containers-preview
https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Docker-for-NET-Developers/Deploy-your-ASPNET-5-App-to-a-Docker-Container-in-five-minutes

Comment: I have seen the channel9 article and videos but just doing so is not working out. I'm using beta7 asp .net vnext.

Comment: Husain, Please do let me know if that works. We can discuss further to hunt your issue down.

Comment: Could you please share your docker file? I hope you are also using asp net beta 7.

Comment: Windows Docker fileFROM windowsservercore

ADD . /app

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["cmd.exe", "/k", "web.cmd"]

Comment: FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta6
Ubuntu Docker file
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["./kestrel"]

Comment: Husain, When you use Visual Studio 2015 and Docker Tools for VS 2015. These docker file automatically get created.

Comment: Viswa, still not able to deploy it successfully.. i'm using asp .net beta7. could u pls try with beta 7? what abt project.json? did you make any changes in that?